# Configure angularjs to set ng-invalid on a form control based on an expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have 2 form controls.

**html**

```html
<input name="password"
       required
       type="password"
       ng-model="form.password" />

<input name="confirmPassword"
       required
       type="password"
       custom-validator
       ng-model="form.confirmPassword" />
```

Currently they work independently and in the scenario where password is invalid, angularjs still (rightly so) sets the confirmPassword input's class to ng-invalid if the confirmPassword control's input is invalid.

I need to be able to add a conditional somewhere, so that the 'ng-invalid' class only gets set IF the first control is $valid (form.password.$valid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use a custom $validator directive as documented in [angularjs' developer guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation).

Comment: thank you for trying however, I'm starting to think my question isn't clear enough. I have a custom validator directive, that is not the issue here. The issue is that I don't want ng-invalid class to be set until the other control is $valid, in this case the password input control.

Comment: @Jurg can't your custom validator access the password field validity and only return failure if it is valid and the current field isn't? I don't actually know much about custom validator but it looks like it should be possible, I'll try to come back with some example code.

Comment: @Jurg also I see you have a custom validator on your password field, but I was talking about having one on your confirmPassword field too

Comment: Okay I'll give that a shot, I actually wrote it wrong. The custom-validator is indeed on the confirmPassword. I'm basically checking if the view entered model is the same as the password and setting it to invalid if it doesn't match. As you would expect where the confirm password field needs to match.

Comment: @Jurg I think you can access the password field validity from the scope parameter. If you named your form "myForm", it should be accessible from scope.myForm.password.$validity.

Comment: Okay, I tried that. The issue with that solution is there are so many other ways the form control is invalidated. There is no way of doing that for other invalidating issues. Such as min-length. It's silly because as soon as you touch the control and remove your mouse, it's throwing the errors.

Comment: I fixed it by ng-class="{ 'ng-invalid' : vm.owningForm.password.$valid == true}". Seems like it's the only way.

Comment: @Jurg about your first comment : scope.myForm.password.$validity should agregate all those sources of invalidity, just add your equality check and you should be set. About your second comment : doesn't this omit the equality check? also when checking boolean values, there's no need to compare them to true or false : bool == true is the same as bool, and bool == false is the same as !bool

Comment: Ah yes, so you're right. This would then in theory (I'll test it) always have ng-invalid if the password field is true. Also thanks for the reminder on the bool :)